# What's a font name table and why do so many free fonts have a "minor issue" with its structure?

Tags: font, font-book

Every other free font I install, Font Book complains about a "minor issue" with its "name table structure". What is a name table? What sorts of problems should I expect these "minor issues" to cause?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue with a google font

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In TTF fonts, the "name" table contains information on the font. There's a table [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=iws-chapter08#3054f18b) which, if you're interested, gives you the exact information on what the name table contains.

I've had the same problem with fonts in the past. Most of the time they work fine, although sometimes they won't show up in all applications. With some Googling I [found a guide](http://www.iwebss.com/tech/540-fixing-fonts-with-validation-errors-on-mac) which fixes the name table structure.